# XSLT- Pre Define NameSpace

Tags: parsing, xslt, namespaces

Hi I have an XML that upon each delivery has a different unique named Namespace that I cannot pre determine with standard processes.

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
<Extensions>
  <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
  <Extension>
    <SrcPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>111</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>0</this:SubBegin>
    </SrcPackage>
    <MatPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>222</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>1</this:SubBegin>
    </MatPackage>
    <!-- Stuff -->
  </Extention>
</Extentions>
</ABC>
```

The Next XML delivered could be

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
<Extensions>
  <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
  <Extension>
    <SrcPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>333</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>0</this:SubBegin>
    </SrcPackage>
    <MatPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>444</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>1</this:SubBegin>
    </MatPackage>
    <!-- Stuff -->
  </Extention>
</Extentions>
</ABC>
```

My current XSL stylesheet works on the first XML predefining the Namespace 
But I am looking to find a way to re-define it later on. on the process. I have added a variable to pull the relevant uuid from the Identification element but am not sure how to integrate this. Using the below stylesheet to process any other XML results in false results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="SelOpGroup" select="/ABC/Extensions/Identification"/>

<!-- Pass thru  --->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ABC/Extensions/SrcPackage>
  <xsl:copy>
            <this:ABDList>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="this:ABDList/*"/>
                <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
            </this:ABDList>
            <this:SubBegin><xsl:value-of select="somethingelse"/> </this:SubBegin>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ABC/Extensions/MatPackage>
  <xsl:copy>
            <this:ABDList>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="this:ABDList/*"/>
                <TaggedB>999</TaggedB>
            </this:ABDList >
            <this:SubBegin><xsl:value-of select="somethingelse"/> </this:SubBegin>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
<Extensions>
  <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
  <Extension>
    <SrcPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>333</TaggedValue>
          <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>a value</this:SubBegin>
    </SrcPackage>
    <MatPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>444</TaggedValue>
          <TaggedB>999</TaggedA>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>a value</this:SubBegin>
    </MatPackage>
    <!-- Stuff -->
  </Extention>
</Extentions>
</ABC>
```

Many thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Your last modification is confusing: `<xsl:value-of select="somethingelse"/>` Where is "somethingelse"?

Comment: You now have the wanted, generic transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="SelOpGroup" select="/ABC/Extensions/Identification"/>

  <!-- Pass thru  -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Extension/SrcPackage">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="{'this:ABDList'}" namespace="{$SelOpGroup}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/namespace::*[name()='this']"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="*[name() = 'this:ABDList']/*"/>
                <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="{'this:SubBegin'}" namespace="{$SelOpGroup}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/namespace::*[name()='this']"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'somethingelse'"/>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Extension/MatPackage">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="{'this:ABDList'}" namespace="{$SelOpGroup}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/namespace::*[name()='this']"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="*[name() = 'this:ABDList']/*"/>
                <TaggedB>999</TaggedB>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="{'this:SubBegin'}" namespace="{$SelOpGroup}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/namespace::*[name()='this']"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="'somethingelse'"/>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the first provided XML document**:

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
    <Extensions>
        <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
        <Extension>
            <SrcPackage>
                <this:ABDList>
                    <TaggedValue>111</TaggedValue>
                </this:ABDList>
                <this:SubBegin>0</this:SubBegin>
            </SrcPackage>
            <MatPackage>
                <this:ABDList>
                    <TaggedValue>222</TaggedValue>
                </this:ABDList>
                <this:SubBegin>1</this:SubBegin>
            </MatPackage>
            <!-- Stuff -->
        </Extension>
    </Extensions>
</ABC>
```

**Produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
   <Extensions>
      <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1f15a9-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
      <Extension>
         <SrcPackage>
            <this:ABDList>
               <TaggedValue>111</TaggedValue>
               <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
            </this:ABDList>
            <this:SubBegin>somethingelse</this:SubBegin>
         </SrcPackage>
         <MatPackage>
            <this:ABDList>
               <TaggedValue>222</TaggedValue>
               <TaggedB>999</TaggedB>
            </this:ABDList>
            <this:SubBegin>somethingelse</this:SubBegin>
         </MatPackage><!-- Stuff -->
      </Extension>
   </Extensions>
</ABC>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on the second provided XML document**:

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
<Extensions>
  <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
  <Extension>
    <SrcPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>333</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>0</this:SubBegin>
    </SrcPackage>
    <MatPackage>
        <this:ABDList>
          <TaggedValue>444</TaggedValue>
        </this:ABDList>
        <this:SubBegin>1</this:SubBegin>
    </MatPackage>
    <!-- Stuff -->
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
</ABC>
```

**Again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ABC xmlns:this="urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331" version="1.1">
   <Extensions>
      <Identification>urn:uuid:9b1FFae4-69de-11d2-b6bc-fcab70ff7331</Identification>
      <Extension>
         <SrcPackage>
            <this:ABDList>
               <TaggedValue>333</TaggedValue>
               <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
            </this:ABDList>
            <this:SubBegin>somethingelse</this:SubBegin>
         </SrcPackage>
         <MatPackage>
            <this:ABDList>
               <TaggedValue>444</TaggedValue>
               <TaggedB>999</TaggedB>
            </this:ABDList>
            <this:SubBegin>somethingelse</this:SubBegin>
         </MatPackage><!-- Stuff -->
      </Extension>
   </Extensions>
</ABC>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. Amazing Result as always!

Answer (score 1):

This is bizarre input (what were they smoking?). But since the namespace is only used on one element, ABDList, my approach would be to select the ABDList elements using `*:ABDList` in XSLT 2.0, or `*[local-name()='ABDList']` in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: thanks Michael, Ive updated the question to show more complexity and the requirement to find a way to somehow re define the namespace.

Comment: Nice namespace suggestions with both the versions, plus one.

Comment: If the errant namespace is more widely used, then I would use a transformation pipeline in which the first step normalizes the namespaces, and does nothing else; the second step is then a normal transformation working with sane input.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an XML that upon each delivery has a different unique named
>   Namespace

Someone ahead of you obviously does not understand the purpose of having a namespace.

Perhaps this could work for your unfortunate situation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SrcPackage/*/TaggedValue">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <TaggedA>888</TaggedA>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MatPackage/*/TaggedValue">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <TaggedB>999</TaggedB>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, Yes quite a well respected company is not making it easy for me. I like your response but I will update the question as I need a way to redefine the namespace as I have to also parse elements that utilise the  the this:element name convention.